# Can't access my zencart admin page

Tags: php, zen-cart

For 2 days now I have been trying to access my admin page for the zencart on a site I am working on, I have re-uploaded the whole zencart numerous times and I keep getting a blank page when I go to the admin section.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

We will probably need more details to really be able to help. If you just see a blank page (have you checked the source code in the browser? Is it completely blank?) you will need to check the error logs to be able to trace the problem.

If you are using Zen Cart version 1.3.8a or higher you will have the error logging tool enabled by default, so you can have a look for logging files inside the /catalog/cache folder. Take a look at a few files and look for fatal errors, because you probably will have one of those if you are getting a blank page.

By the way, that kind of error doesn't happen without good reason, What is the last thing you have modified/added to your admin site? A new contribution perhaps?

Comment: THank you for your answer, I viewed the source and it is empty.  I have added nothing new into the zen-cart part of the site.  I had changed information in the other parts of the site, but they are not linked to zencart at all.  I checked the error log and this is what I get.  PS I am very new to zencart, I have searched google and it tells me to check my configure.php page and I keep getting an access denied when I upload it.  I did it manually and it went up fine. Anyways this is the errors in my log:

Comment: [16-Jun-2011 19:32:25] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ags/public_html/zencart/lemonade/includes/classes/logger.php:127) in /home/ags/public_html/zencart/includes/functions/sessions.php on line 114

Comment: [16-Jun-2011 ] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/ags/public_html/zencart/lemonade/includes/classes/logger.php:127) in /home/ags/public_html/zencart/includes/functions/sessions.php on line 114
 PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ags/public_html/zencart/lemonade/includes/classes/logger.php:127) in /home/ags/public_html/zencart/lemonade/includes/init_includes/init_templates.php on line 55

Comment: [16-Jun-2011 19:32:25] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ags/public_html/zencart/lemonade/includes/classes/logger.php:127) in /home/ags/public_html/zencart/lemonade/includes/functions/general.php on line 21

Comment: Take a look at the logger class, line 127. This error means that this file has echo'ed some text to the browser (or has some text, even a space or a blank line outside php blocks) and this is bad for the working of zen-cart.

Comment: Logger is only 63 lines long.  Check your ftp setup to see that you're not inserting blank lines into the file.  Also you should change your admin name now that you posted it on stackoverflow, and try to avoid posting it in the future.  The idea is to not give hackers a headstart.

Comment: Agree with @Scott, logger.php should have 63 lines only. If you have blank lines after the closing php tag (`?>`), remove them. Or you can just remove the closing tag at line 63 (remove the `?>`).